# RMI Connection refused

Tags: rmi

When I started RMI service and then I tried to connect to it and then an exception happened, which says "connection refused", but I try to telnet to RMI service what can establish the connection. My RMI server running on a Linux machine and client server is a web server.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like if your `RMI-Registry` is not running. Usually u can test this if you lookup netstat outputs.

In Linux:

```
rmiregistry &
```

You can also test if it is present with

```
ps aux | grep rmiregistry
```

Comment: After running rmiregistry and restart rmi service I still got connection refused

Comment: @fyr Unlikely. If the Registry wasn't running his service would be unable to bind. He is past that and trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused to what? If it was 127.0.0.1 and you were expecting a remote address, see item A.1 of the [RMI FAQ](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html).